# Why does my template specialization fail to compile?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class MyRNG{
public:
    T Rand(){return T();};
};

template<typename RNG, typename = void>
struct GetDataTypeOf;

template<typename RNG>
struct GetDataTypeOf<RNG, decltype(std::declval<RNG>().Rand())> {
    typedef decltype(std::declval<RNG>().Rand()) type;
};

template<typename RNG>
using DataTypeOf = typename GetDataTypeOf<RNG>::type;

int main(){
    std::cout << typeid(DataTypeOf<MyRNG<int>>).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Error:

```
incomplete type is not allowed
using DataTypeOf = typename GetDataTypeOf<RNG>::type;
                              ^
detected during instantiation of type "DataTypeOf<MyRNG<int>>" at line 22
```

It seems that `GetDataTypeOf<MyRNG<int>>` does not match any of the specialized class definitions. Why could that be?

Compiler: gcc 9.4.0

Comment: `decltype(std::declval<RNG>().Rand())` isn't `void`. Did you mean `decltype(void(std::declval<RNG>().Rand()))`?

Comment: Can you explain why adding void works? I don't have much understanding of template metaprogramming.

Comment: Your specialization is used when `std::declval<RNG>().Rand()` is valid for a given `RNG`, AND its return type (as returned by `decltype`) matches the second template argument, which is `void`. The version I suggested casts the returned value to `void` (even though this always returnd `void`, it still checks that the expression is valid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that `decltype(std::declval<RNG>().Rand())` is not `void`. This means that you've provided the specialization not for `void` but for the return type `T`.

One way to solve this is to add `void` to do explicit conversion so that the specialization becomes a specialization for `void` as shown below:

```
template<typename RNG>
//---------------------------------vvvv-------------------------->added void here
struct GetDataTypeOf<RNG, decltype(void(std::declval<RNG>().Rand()))> {
    typedef decltype(std::declval<RNG>().Rand()) type;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/x81d6h9Y3)

Comment: (2) makes little sense, you might as well just do `template <typename RNG> using DataTypeOf = decltype(...);`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Right. Updated(removed the 2nd method).